# Not getting the values from model class into adapter

Tags: android

I have a model class "Finance" and I need to use the Finance class in my adapter but I am not able to do that. I am getting Finance class object as null. Can anyone help me please.

`Adapter`

```
    partyName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Finance finance =new Finance() ;
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name_of_extra", finance);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

`Finance.class`

```
public class Finance implements Parcelable {

    private String partyName;
    private String bankName;
    private Date reminderDate;
    private int id;
    private Date expiryDate;
    private String amount;
    private String chequeNumber;
    private String reminder;
    private boolean closed=false;


    public Finance() {

    }

    public Finance(String partyName, String bankName,String reminder, int id) {
        this.partyName = partyName;
        this.bankName = bankName;
        this.reminder = reminder;
        this.id = id;

    }

    protected Finance(Parcel in) {
        partyName = in.readString();
        bankName = in.readString();
        id = in.readInt();
        amount = in.readString();
        chequeNumber = in.readString();
        reminder = in.readString();
        closed = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Finance> CREATOR = new Creator<Finance>() {
        @Override
        public Finance createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Finance(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Finance[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Finance[size];
        }
    };

    public String getPartyName() {
        return partyName;
    }

    public void setPartyName(String partyName) {
        this.partyName = partyName;
    }

    public String getChequeNumber() {
        return chequeNumber;
    }

    public void setChequeNumber(String chequeNumber) {
        this.chequeNumber = chequeNumber;
    }

    public Date getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(Date expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getBankName() {
        return bankName;
    }

    public void setBankName(String bankName) {
        this.bankName = bankName;
    }

    public String getReminder() {
        return reminder;
    }

    public void setReminder(String reminder) {
        this.reminder = reminder;
    }

    public Date getReminderDate() {
        return reminderDate;
    }

    public void setReminderDate(Date reminderDate) {
        this.reminderDate = reminderDate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isClosed() {
        return closed;
    }

    public void setClosed(boolean closed) {
        this.closed = closed;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(partyName);
        dest.writeString(bankName);
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(amount);
        dest.writeString(chequeNumber);
        dest.writeString(reminder);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (closed ? 1 : 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of your MainActivity where you try to get the passed Finance object from the intent.

Comment: Please share your adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

check you button click you are not set any value in this on button click you created a new object and you didn't pass any value for it so it's `null`

use this and change values as you want

```
    Finance finance =new Finance("test","test","test",1) ;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name_of_extra", finance);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
Finance finance =new Finance() ;
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name_of_extra", finance);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not implementing it right,actually you are not passing the arguments in your constructor, it should be like:

```
Finance finance =new Finance("party_name","bank_name","reminder",1) ;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name_of_extra", finance);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
Finance finance = new Finance();
finance.setPartyName("test_name_1");
finance.setBankName("test_name_2");
finance.setReminder("test_name_3");
finance.setId(1);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name_of_extra", finance);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

You can always have a check on null reference like:

```
if(finance!=null){
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("name_of_extra", finance);
 context.startActivity(intent);
}
```